# Labeling along the axes, matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

How do I place the labeling of the axes inside of the graph?

Right now i have this:

[image]

I want the numbering inside of the graph, along the axes.

Thanks,
Cro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the matplotlib [spine placement demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html) you'd find that you can shift the spines using `ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.linspace(-3,3)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(-4,10)
ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help and the link!